# Angular-Material: Error with md-stretch-tabs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm currently developing and angular-based app.

PROBLEM: I added `md-stretch-tabs` to my `md-tabs` element but, when i switch to tab#2 my tab retracts like if there's not enought space to `flex`.
Is it a problem of dependecies or code itself?

EDIT:added full code.

```js
var app = angular.module('BetaApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('SideNavController', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
 $scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
  $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
 };
 $scope.closeLeftMenu = function() {
  $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
 };
});

app.config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
 var customPrimary = {
  '50': '#7099cd',
  '100': '#5d8bc7',
  '200': '#4a7ec0',
  '300': '#3e71b3',
  '400': '#3865a0',
  '500': '#31598d',
  '600': '#2a4d7a',
  '700': '#244167',
  '800': '#1d3554',
  '900': '#172941',
  'A100': '#83a6d4',
  'A200': '#96b4db',
  'A400': '#a9c1e1',
  'A700': '#101d2e',
  'contrastDefaultColor': 'light'
 };
 $mdThemingProvider
 .definePalette('customPrimary', 
              customPrimary);

 var customAccent = {
        '50': '#1c5956',
        '100': '#226d68',
        '200': '#28807b',
        '300': '#2e948e',
        '400': '#34a7a1',
        '500': '#3abab3',
        '600': '#5bccc6',
        '700': '#6fd2cd',
        '800': '#82d8d3',
        '900': '#96deda',
        'A100': '#5bccc6',
        'A200': '#48c6bf',
        'A400': '#3abab3',
        'A700': '#a9e4e1',
  'contrastDefaultColor': 'light'
 };
 $mdThemingProvider
 .definePalette('customAccent', 
              customAccent);

 var customWarn = {
  '50': '#f7d1cb',
  '100': '#f4bdb5',
  '200': '#f1a99f',
  '300': '#ee9688',
  '400': '#ea8272',
  '500': '#e76e5c',
  '600': '#e45a46',
  '700': '#e04630',
  '800': '#d73720',
  '900': '#c1321c',
  'A100': '#fbe5e1',
  'A200': '#fef8f8',
  'A400': '#ffffff',
  'A700': '#aa2c19',
  'contrastDefaultColor': 'dark'

 
 };
 $mdThemingProvider
 .definePalette('customWarn', 
              customWarn);

 $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
 .primaryPalette('customPrimary')
 .accentPalette('customAccent')
 .warnPalette('customWarn');
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" >
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
</head>


<!--======================================================================================================================================-->
<!--
<md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">face</md-icon>
<i class="material-icons">menu</i>
-->
<!--======================================================================================================================================-->



<body ng-app="BetaApp" ng-cloak layout="column" ng-controller="SideNavController">

 <md-toolbar md-whiteframe="3">
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
   <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More" ng-click="openLeftMenu()">
    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
   </md-button>
   <span>WideView</span>
   <!-- fill up the space between left and right area -->
   <span flex></span>
   <md-button class="md-icon-button">
    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
   </md-button>
   <md-button class="md-icon-button">
    <i class="material-icons">filter_list</i>
   </md-button>
   <md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
     <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content>
     <md-menu-item>
      <md-button ng-click="doSomething()"><md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">refresh</md-icon>Refresh</md-button>
     </md-menu-item>
     <md-menu-item>
      <md-button ng-click="doSomething()"><md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">view_quilt</md-icon>Change View</md-button>
     </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
   </md-menu>
   
  </div>
 </md-toolbar>

 <div layout="row" flex>
  <md-content>


   <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-stretch-tabs="always">
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi.</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
          <span flex></span>
         <md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
          <label>Address</label>
          <input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
          <label>Address</label>
          <input>
        </md-input-container>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>


  </md-content>



  <md-fab-speed-dial md-direction="up" class="md-scale md-fab-bottom-right">
   <md-fab-trigger>
    <md-button aria-label="" class="md-accent md-fab">  
     <i class="material-icons">add</i>   
    </md-button>
   </md-fab-trigger>
   <md-fab-actions>
    <md-button aria-label="" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
     <i class="material-icons">share</i>  
    </md-button>
    <md-button aria-label="" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
     <i class="material-icons md-accent">add_a_photo</i>   
    </md-button>
    <md-button aria-label="" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
     <i class="material-icons">create</i>   
    </md-button>
   </md-fab-actions>
  </md-fab-speed-dial>




  <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left" md-whiteframe="3" layout="column">
   <div layout="row">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button">
     <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">new_releases</md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <span flex></span>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="closeLeftMenu()">
     <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">arrow_forward</md-icon>
    </md-button>

   </div>
   <md-card md-whiteframe="2">
    <md-card-header>

     <md-card-avatar>
      <img class="md-user-avatar" src="images/BigDave.png"/>
     </md-card-avatar>
     <md-card-header-text>
      <div layout="row">
       <div layout="column">
        <span class="md-title">BigDave</span>
        <span class="md-subhead">logged in</span>
       </div>
       <span flex></span>
       <md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
         <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
        </md-button>
        <md-menu-content>
         <md-menu-item>
          <md-button ng-click="doSomething()"><md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">account_box</md-icon>Settings</md-button>
         </md-menu-item>
         <md-menu-item>
          <md-button ng-click="doSomething()"><md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">exit_to_app</md-icon>Log out</md-button>
         </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
       </md-menu>
      </div>
     </md-card-header-text>
    </md-card-header>
   </md-card>
<md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button></md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button></md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button></md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button></md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button></md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button></md-menu-item>
<a class="ms-navigation-button ng-scope md-default-theme"e>
<i class="icon s16 icon-calendar-today" ng-if="node.icon"></i>
<span class="title ng-scope ng-binding flex" translate="" flex="">Calendar</span>
 </a>
  </md-sidenav>

  


  


 </div>


 <!--======================================================================================================================================-->


 <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
 <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Angular Material Library -->
 <script src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/vXByKW

Comment: ok can i give you my entire code. just to see if are my local files that give this problem.

Comment: It's possible one of your AngularJS or Angular Material files is an old version. In my CodePen click on Settings to view the CSS and JavaScript files and see if they match up with yours.

Comment: Yes, and it seems all up to date

Comment: I also tried to download all the dependencies locally but this bug is still there. I thinks that's probably a code error but i can't find where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the attributes of the `div` that contains your `md-tabs`:

```
<div layout="row" flex>
```

if you replace it with just this

```
<div>
```

it works fine - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/WGZKjA?editors=1000)

Comment: hum...how can i do that? I'm not expert of this forum.

Comment: This is not working in the case of new version of angular-material (1.1.5)